# FAQ questions should be exempt from required tags

Tags: feature-request, edits, meta

I was working with a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) that was a part of the FAQ, and it wouldn't let me submit the changes because it "must include one of these tags – [bug] [feature-request] [discussion] [support]".

Do all future edits to FAQs also require one of those tags?  This means that you are effectively [limited to *three* tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) specific to the question's content, and might have to remove a good tag in order to make room for [support] or [discussion].  Doesn't FAQ already imply [support]?

Can questions already tagged as [faq] (a locked, moderator-only tag) be exempt from  required tags?

Though I of course don't know the backend implementation, if [faq] was added to the list of required tags (and the missing-required-tag error message cleaned up so that non-moderators weren't prompted to use it) while still being a locked tag, then any 2k user editing an FAQ would "meet" the required-tag requirement, without allowing non-moderators to add or remove [faq].

Comment: +1 - Same problem here. I have been obliged to take out a good tag and put a silly one in order to comply with the rule.

Comment: As I've flirted with FAQ additions and editing, this has been a nuisance and just another barrier to improvement.  There are several areas of the FAQ that could be better organized and updated.

Answer (score 3):

Just make them either discussion or support, which is usually what a FAQ is.

E.g. How can I vote someone's answer up? [support](/questions/tagged/support)

Can we please see the number of up / down votes? [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

Comment: IMHO, anything tagged with the "offical"/locked [faq] already implies [support].