# Add [faq-update-request] to the required Meta tags?

Tags: feature-request, meta, required-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FAQ questions should be exempt from required tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30729/faq-questions-should-be-exempt-from-required-tags)

Meta requires at least one of the following tags to be present in a question:

> must include one of these tags -- 'bug feature-request discussion support'

Might it be worth adding [faq-update-request](/questions/tagged/faq-update-request) to this? I posted a FAQ update proposal where I don't think any of the above tags are particularly appropriate... but perhaps I'm misinterpreting their meaning.

Comment: Erm, oops... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30729/faq-questions-should-be-exempt-from-required-tags

Comment: When something is currently `[faq-proposed]`, it seems like a `[discussion]` tag is the best choice. After all, it's still open for discussion as long as it's not an official FAQ. We want the community to contribute.

Comment: @Cody: But that's the case for `bug` and `feature-request` too. In fact, arguably _every_ post on meta is by definition "open for discussion".

Comment: Incidentally, I just realised that there is a difference between the [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and questions tagged `faq`. I was referring to the former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've got a [faq-update-request](/questions/tagged/faq-update-request), then you're requesting a change to the system. That falls very neatly under the definition of [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

The only reason it's so bulkily phrased as a tag is because [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) is already a very special tag for a very different role, so we need a clear tag that indicates when a question is talking about the `/faq` page. Sometimes we also use [site-faq](/questions/tagged/site-faq) when talking about that page, but there hasn't been a clear consistency in that yet. Perhaps that'll need some visitation, but in either scenario we can still stick with using [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as your required tag.

Comment: \*nods\*. Understood.